# Error after Installing CiviCRM 4.6.4 on Drupal 6, drupal attempts to reinstall at localhost/drupal

Tags: drupal, installation, drupal-6

I have recently installed Drupal 6 on WAMP, then I downloaded CiviCRM 4.6.4 for Drupal 6. I followed the installation offered on wiki.civicrm.org and everything went very smoothly. When I attempted to follow the final step of "Return to Drupal and enable the CiviCRM module http:///admin/build/modules. Check the box next to CiviCRM, then scroll to the bottom of the page and click the "Save configuration" button.". I punch in localhost/drupal into my browser and Drupal attempts to install itself again. I pressed "Install Drupal in English" and it timed out and showed me this "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\drupal\includes\file.inc on line 1078". Help please!!

Comment: Curious -- why Drupal 6, which is essentially end of lifed and unsupported? (actually in a few weeks, but still... https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol )

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a good reason why you have chosen to use Drupal 6, I would suggest that you use Drupal 7 instead.  As Laryn points out Drupal will reach end of life soon.  Things are more likely to go smoothly if you are using Drupal 7 and you also find it easier to get help.

I would also recommend that you use the latest version of CiviCRM - currently 4.6.12 (or 4.7.1).

Comment: The internship I recently obtained required that I use Drupal 6, and I installed civiCRM 4.7.1 and Drupal said that it is not compatible with that version of CiviCRM. In any event I got it to work and I want to thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working but strange that they require Drupal 6.